# System Level File.Encrypt method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, encryption

I am looking for simple file encryption method for .NET 2.0 similar to File.Encrypt but that will allow access to all the users that have administrative privileges on the system.

I would like not to use any symmetric/asymmetric encryption because of key management hassle that comes with it.

Is there any Windows OS API that can encrypt file and have transparent access for administrative users?

Please provide code example or link to example if it's .NET method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is well suited to be handled by an [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs).

On windows, this means you just put the unencrypted file in a folder where only administrative users (or users of a specific **role**) have access to, by setting appropriate owner and read/write permissions.

Encryption always requires a key, somewhere, somehow.

**EDIT:** you can set access permissions programmatically after saving the file. Any file read (even `File.ReadAllLines()` and the like) will simply fail if the application was started by a user without the necessary roles.

Comment: Code example please?

Comment: You can start from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: [This](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_webservices/security/article.php/c14315/The-Basics-of-Manipulating-File-Access-Control-Lists-with-C.htm) might also help. Sorry I cannot give you any copy & paste example here, you'll have to understand what you are doing. Security is based on you understanding it, not copy & pasting code.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to look a bit more into leveraging [UAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wd8zba(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: What would happen if someone will access hard drive without access to the system? Would they be able to read the file?

Comment: Yes, obviously. If you need to protect against someone taking PHYSICALLY your drive and analyzing it as a secondary drive with, say, Linux then you'll need file-level encryption. The above requires you to go through the actual OS functions.